# role hierarchy inheritance - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, acl, hierarchical-data

I've problem with my hierarchical role in *security.yml*

#### role_hierarchy

```
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_PILOT, ROLE_EXPERT]
    ROLE_PILOT: ROLE_PRODIVER
    ROLE_PROVIDER: ROLE_PROVIDER_EXTERNAL
    ROLE_PROVIDER_EXTERNAL: ROLE_USER
```

When i'm using *is_granted* in TWIG  :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_PROVIDER_EXTERNAL') %}
 <li class="dropdown">[...]</li>
{% endif %}
```

Normally the ROLE_PILOT should be able to view this HTML element with the inheritance of roles. But if user is connected in ROLE_PILOT, HTML element cannot display for him...

Anyone have an idea for my problem ?
Thx

Comment: I think the rules must be written top to bottom, so that the weakest rule is on the top, not at the bottom.

Comment: I tried, however, no change.
The PILOT is inherited rights PROVIDER with my hierarchy no ?!

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->getContainer()->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles'))` (in a controller) returns?

Comment: I've the same hierarchy but in Php instead of Yaml.
Array of 5 Roles :
(...Simplified array...)
`ROLE_PROVIDER_EXTERNAL => ["ROLE_USER"]
ROLE_PROVIDER => ["ROLE_PROVIDER_EXTERNAL"]
ROLE_PILOT =>["ROLE_PRODIVER"]
ROLE_ADMIN => ["ROLE_PILOT", "ROLE_EXPERT"]
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows:

```
ROLE_PILOT: ROLE_PRODIVER
```

Try changing it to:

```
ROLE_PILOT: ROLE_PROVIDER
```

Comment: I found this big mistake yesterday. The problem is solved, my hierarchy of roles is OK.